# Nesting "IF" Statements in Google Sheets to categorize numbers

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, nested

I am trying to categorize numbers based on various levels of qualifications standards. For instance, Qualification "A" requires a number between 44.09 and 35.60. Qualification "B" requires a number between 35.59 and 29.30. Finally, qualification "C" requires a number at or less than 29.29. If the number is above the highest "A" qualification of 44.09, then an "X" should be displayed.

B2 happens to be the cell this formula is categorizing.

I have tried nesting "IF" statements in the following manner, however the formula incorrectly classifies the number.

```
=IF(44.09>=B2>35.59,"A", IF(35.59>=B2>29.29,"B", IF(B2<=29.29,"C","X")))
```

When I input "20" into "B2", the formula will classify it as "A", even though it should be "C".

Perhaps I have the "<>=" statements incorrectly stated, but I have tried fixing them to no avail. How can I change the formula to correctly classify these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(B2<29.29,"C",
  IF(B2<=35.59,"B",
    IF(B2<=44.09,"A","X")))
```

Comment: thank you! way simpler, especially when building a big spreadsheet with many different qualification standards.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=IF((44.09>=B2)*(B2>35.59), "A", 
 IF((35.59>=B2)*(B2>29.29), "B", 
 IF(B2<=29.29,              "C", "X")))
```

see: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(B2,{-999,"C"; 29.291,"B"; 35.591,"A"; 44.091,"X"},2,TRUE))`

Here, `B2` is simply looked up within a virtual array containing two columns: the first with lower limits at each tier and the second with return values. Since the search column is in strict ascending order, `TRUE` will return the last threshold passed if no exact match is found.

Note: If your values will never dip below 0, you can change the `-999` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make range (between y and x) comparison like that. You have to use the `AND` keyword to test for higher than and lower than at the same time:

```
=IF(AND(44.09>=B2, B2>=35.6),"A", IF(AND(36>B2, B2>=29.3),"B", IF(B2<29.3,"C","X")))
```

You can build more complex conditions that way, for example using `OR`, and you are not restricted to two conditions, you can expand to more.